# Tensorflow version mismatch on conda environments

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I had initially installed tf-nightly by mistake and later uninstalled it. Now, I have installed two different versions of tensorflow on two different conda environments (tf1.14-gpu and tf2.0-gpu). When I execute the command

`conda list -n tf1.14-gpu tensorflow` it shows the following output

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                1.14.0          gpu_py36h3fb9ad6_0  
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          gpu_py36he45bfe2_0  
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0  
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0               h0d30ee6_0
```

When I execute the command `conda list -n tf2.0-gpu tensorflow` it shows the following output

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                2.1.0           gpu_py36h2e5cdaa_0  
tensorflow-base           2.1.0           gpu_py36h6c5654b_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0              pyhd54b08b_0  
tensorflow-gpu            2.1.0                h0d30ee6_0
```

But in both the environments when i import tensorflow and check for its version, it gives the same output as `'2.2.0-dev20200218'` which I assume is the version for tensorflow nightly build. I am not able to use this version for my existing models. I tried uninstalling anaconda and reinstalling the two environments with tensorflow 1.14 and tensorflow 2.0, but it tensorflow version still shows the same as `'2.2.0-dev20200218'`. Any idea how to overcome this ?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the Python program(s) using the correct environment? Have you tried running a script which does nothing but check the version, straight from the command line?

Comment: Yes. I activate the conda environment and then run the python scripts. I have directly checked the tensorflow version inside a environment's python shell. Regardless of the environment, it gives me the same tf version as `2.2.0-dev20200218`

Answer (score 0):

I ran to the same problem. Could it be possible that you installed `tf-nightly` using pip and not Conda? But when you run `import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)`it picks up the global pip version which is troublesome to get rid of?

p.s. Sorry that I'm posting instead of commenting. Don't have 50 reputation points yet.

Comment: I  finally solved it. I dunno how but somehow tensorflow-nightly was still present in .local/lib/python3.6/site-packages and it was getting imported always. When I try to uninstall tf-nightly, it says not installed. So, I manually deleted the package and now everything runs fine for me.